# How do I loop Through a MongoDB Array with React JS to Render a Table?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, react-redux

In my MERN application, I am trying to create an admin dashboard component. This component will show a table with user information. The information is pulled from a MongoDB collection and then rendered on to a table.

Currently, I am using a for loop to iterate through the array, but it would be much nicer to user the .map Javascript function instead.

However, when I switch the below code to a .map function instead of a for loop, it doesn't work, why this is happening makes no sense to me.

When I try to replace the loop with the map function, it seems like the code tries to map the array before it gets defined. The array gets defined via a promise call from a Redux reducer. So before the App sets the array to the state, the code calls the map function and breaks.

When I use the for loop, for some magical reason, it waits for my array to be set and I can display the table.

Any ideas as to why I can't use the .map function in this case but a for loop works perfectly? Below is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { Table, Button, Container } from "reactstrap"

class AdminProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.renderTable = this.renderTable.bind(this)
    this.renderTableBody = this.renderTableBody.bind(this)
  }

  renderTableBody() {
    const body = document.getElementById("table-body")
    const length = this.props.users.length
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.users.length; i++) {
      const row = document.createElement("tr")
      row.id = this.props.users[i].discord_id
      const col1 = document.createElement("td")
      col1.innerText = this.props.users[i].discord_id
      const col2 = document.createElement("td")
      col2.innerText = this.props.users[i].email
      const date = new Date(this.props.users[i].pay_date)
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
      const col3 = document.createElement("td")
      col3.innerText = date.toLocaleDateString()
      const col4 = document.createElement("td")
      col4.innerText = this.props.users[i].status
      const col5 = document.createElement("td")
      col5.setAttribute("name", "button-column")
      col5.style.display = "inline-block"

      const button1 = document.createElement("Button")
      const button2 = document.createElement("Button")
      const button3 = document.createElement("Button")
      //button1.style.alignSelf = "center"
      button1.setAttribute("class", "btn-icon btn-simple btn btn-info btn-sm")
      button2.setAttribute(
        "class",
        "btn-icon btn-simple btn btn-success btn-sm"
      )
      button3.setAttribute("class", "btn-icon btn-simple btn btn-danger btn-sm")
      const button1icon = document.createElement("i")
      const button2icon = document.createElement("i")
      const button3icon = document.createElement("i")
      button1icon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-user")
      button1icon.setAttribute("color", "info")
      button1icon.setAttribute("size", "sm")
      button2icon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-edit")
      button2icon.setAttribute("color", "success")
      button2icon.setAttribute("size", "sm")
      button3icon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-times")
      button3icon.setAttribute("color", "danger")
      button3icon.setAttribute("size", "sm")
      button1.appendChild(button1icon)
      button2.appendChild(button2icon)
      button3.appendChild(button3icon)

      col5.appendChild(button1)
      col5.appendChild(button2)
      col5.appendChild(button3)
      row.appendChild(col1)
      row.appendChild(col2)
      row.appendChild(col3)
      row.appendChild(col4)
      row.appendChild(col5)
      body.appendChild(row)
      if (length === i) {
        break
      }
    }
    // this.renderButtons()
  }
  // renderButtons() {
  //   const rows = document.getElementsByName("button-column")
  //   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  //     ReactDOM.render(
  //       <Container>
  //         <Button className="btn-icon btn-simple" color="info" size="sm">
  //           <i className="fa fa-user" />
  //         </Button>
  //         <Button className="btn-icon btn-simple" color="success" size="sm">
  //           <i className="fa fa-edit" />
  //         </Button>
  //         <Button className="btn-icon btn-simple" color="danger" size="sm">
  //           <i className="fa fa-times" />
  //         </Button>
  //       </Container>,
  //       document.querySelector(rows[i].name)
  //     )
  //   }
  // }
  renderTable() {
    console.log(this.props.users)
    return (
      <Table responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="text-left">ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Next Payment</th>
            <th className="text-left">Status</th>
            <th className="text-left">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body">{this.renderTableBody()}</tbody>
      </Table>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>WELCOME ADMIN!</h1>
        <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center" }} S>
          Users
        </h4>
        {this.renderTable()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
    card: state.card,
    stock: state.stock,
    users: state.users
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminProfile)
```

The result I want is cleaner code that results in less errors. The for loop can result in the table being rendered twice or thrice in some cases.

Comment: any help is appreciated! thank you very much

Comment: What is the error you get when you use .map(). And what is the initial state you set for state.users in your reducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the initial state for props.users? Just to be clear it should be initialized as an empty array. It's hard to tell without an error.

Second thing I would try is turning making sure your props.users is an array by wrapping it in Array.from(this.props.users).

A third thing, that may help your code look cleaner, is that rather than creating elements and adding attributes to them after creation is using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). So rather than looping through and creating elements you just do it dynamically.

```
Array.from(this.props.users).map(user => {
   return (
      `<tr key=${user.id} id=${user.id}>
        <td>${user.name}</td> // or whatever info your trying to display 
      </tr>`
   )
})
```

Comment: this worked without me having to do anything on Redux or the backend.

Thank you! Life saver!